# ValidateAntiForgeryToken breaks read on .NET Core with IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I am doing a basic read and write functionality to a IdentityServer4 application using .NET Core 2.0  and have come across an issue.  When trying to load clients the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute seem to break my update.

I know that EF core does not support lazy loading so we are using an Unit Of Work pattern. I would create separate repositories for Client, ClientScopes, Secrets, etc. and grab the data for each. I will pass in a Func<> to allow filtering when grabbing ClientScopes etc.  So a method call would look like this

```
ClientScopeResitory.GetAll(a => a.Client.Id == id)
```

which would then access the dbset like this

```
public IEnumerable GetAll(Func<T, object> predicate == null)
{
    return predicate != null ? dbset.Where(predicate) : dbset
}
```

My issue is when loading the client in my read operation this works just fine.  However when using the same code in my update where the ValidateAntiForgeryToken is present it breaks.  What happens is in the creation of the repository during the read, the Clients are loaded in with the dbset. However, in the update, the clients are not.  When the ValidateAntiForgery attribute is removed.  The clients are loaded again and the update works fine.  Anyone have any ideas what is going on.  I can supply full code upon request.  Thanks in advance.

Also, I apologies for any bad grammar or spelling, I wrote this in a hurry

Comment: can you give us an example where you are using `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`?

Comment: yea `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` has nothing to do with `Entity Framework Core`. Are you sure you're getting the right data binded into your view model before transforming them into domain models and entities?

Comment: @David Liang.  I know thats what is tripping me out so bad!  The model is irrelovant here.  The problem is the clients are not being loading in with the creation of the repository.  Any mapping happens way after the fact or actual updating happens after the fact.  The repository seems to decide wether to gather the client when setting the dbset depending on wether or not the attribute exists on the controller creating it.  I just got home so I will load up some code here soon

Comment: @mvermef  Im gonna load up some code here in a minute.